# How would you translate the line 我在寻人启事上看见我身份证办好 from the movie 地久天长

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm having trouble understanding what `我在寻人启事上看见我身份证办好` means in the following dialogue. Here is some context:

A young guy gets mad at his parents and decides to go away leaving no traces (he goes missing). His parents then write a "missing person notice". Long after the guy shows again and in this particular scene he's at home with his parents and a group of new friends. While the young guy is talking with his friends his mom asks him to come over for a moment and the following dialogue goes on:

1. **Mom:** Xingxing, are they from your school?
2. **Xingxing:** No.
3. **Mom:** Then who are they?
4. **Xingxing:** Friends.
5. **Mom:** Friends? They don't go to school?
6. **Xingxing:** No. Just like me.
7. **Mom:** Xingxing, do you know how long  we've been looking for you? Can't you see you're letting everyone down?
8. **Xingxing:** What do I care? **我在寻人启事上看见我身份证办好** [He walks away]

The English subtitles translate it as "The missing person notice said I have an ID card now.", but what does that mean? I think the translation is not correct cause I can't make a sense of it.

This is the missing person notice:

[image]

Comment: What's the name of the movie, since this sentence sounds wired.

Comment: @Manx: The movie is "地久天长", see here: https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9C%B0%E4%B9%85%E5%A4%A9%E9%95%BF_(%E7%94%B5%E5%BD%B1). You can find it on YT with Chinese subtitles with the following title: "2019年柏林最佳男女主角 王小帅的野心史诗之作 天长地久", scene is at 1:38:50

Comment: I see, 我在寻人启事上看见我身份证办好了 make sense, means he knows he had a ID card now from the 寻人启事.

Comment: When you ask for help with translation on this site, please show what parts of the sentence you've already translated and which part you don't understand.

Comment: The OP writes *The English subtitles translate that as "The missing person notice said I have an ID card now."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2nd last sentence in the photo saying that "你的身份证已经给你办理好，希望你早日回家." "We have applied the ID card for you and now it is ready. Hope you come back home soon." Looks like the ID card is what the kid wants. Parents are using it to attract him. Later on, he did come home, but just to pick it up. He says "我在寻人启事上看见我身份证办好." It is confusing if you see the sentence without context. This sentence missed several parts it should be:

我在寻人启事上看见我（的）身份证（已经）办好（了）

Comment: Thank you! Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

首先，翻译是正确的。但男孩想表达的并不是字母意义上的身份证已经办理完毕，而是他认为自己其实并不重要，也根本不在乎家人正在寻找他。